# Synchronous communication microservices

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, microservices

I understand that micro-services are a good way to separate contexts and allow us to create smaller models. One of the ways to achieve decoupling is asynchronous publish/subscribe communication between micro-services.

Let's say a micro-service **A** is in charge to process a request and for that it needs information which are stored in micro-service **B**.
One of the ways to solve this is, is to make micro-service **A** to subscribe to events from micro-service **B**, copy portion of needed data to it's data storage and use it for future processing.

Now, if user sends a request to micro-service **A** to process something, and micro-service **A** did not process latest events from micro-service **B**, would it be a better way to use synchronous communication, and request that portion of data directly? If yes, is that considered a "violation" of current design and coupling?

Could it also be considered as a wrong modeling? Such as - if the data were needed in **A** context, then it should have been part of that context from start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could it also be considered as a wrong modeling? Such as - if the data were needed in A context, then it should have been part of that context from start.

Yes, it could be.

- [The Known Unknowns of SOA](http://udidahan.com/2010/11/15/the-known-unknowns-of-soa/)
- [Secret of Better UI Composition](http://particular.net/blog/secret-of-better-ui-composition)

In summary, if micro-service B is the technical authority for the data that you need in this use case, then micro-service B should be providing that capability.

> is that considered a "violation" of current design and coupling?

In that design, if micro-service B is unavailable, then micro-service A can't provide value.  That sounds like coupling to me.

My guess, if you are trapped in this pattern, would be to communicate synchronously with B, but with a local cache of the data for those occasions when B isn't available.

Some of the problems go away if the data being shared is immutable.

> This of course works only when working with cached data is allowed by business, otherwise A would need to own the data or throw an exception

If the writer of the data is B, then any data seen by A *is* cached data; service B could be changing the data while A is looking at it.  If A is making a decision that requires a live copy of data written by B, then you've got a bigger problem -- your service boundaries are in the wrong place.

Comment: "My guess, if you are trapped in this pattern, would be to communicate synchronously with B, but with a local cache of the data for those occasions when B isn't available." This of course works only when working with cached data is allowed by business, otherwise A would need to own the data or throw an exception?